# AWS_cloudfront_response_header

Tags: header, response

I would like to remove the server as cloudfront while inspecting the website. I tried to create a Response Header policy and updated the remove header as Server. But, It shows the server as cloudfront while inspecting it. How to remove the server as cloudfront from the viewer response manually in the aws console?

Comment: You should really consider your tags better, because that's how people find your question. And `header` and `response` are basically useless as tags.